# jQuery Sortable: connect lists and attribute sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working with a multidimensional matrix, in which i want to sort rows.

Part one of problem is, i want only elements with the same attribute to be sortabe:

(the actual structure is way more complex, but i my problem would be solved on this example, i will be able to poject it to my structure...)

**HTML:**

```
<!-- header for each horizontal item -->
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="head">ItemID</div>
    <div class="sortItemHead" parent-id="0">1</div>
    <div class="sortItemHead" parent-id="1">2</div>
    <div class="sortItemHead" parent-id="1">3</div>
    <div class="sortItemHead" parent-id="0">4</div>
    <div class="sortItemHead" parent-id="0">5</div>
</div>

<!-- values for each horizontal key/value pair-->
<div class="sortable">
    <div class="head">Name</div>
    <div class="sortItem" parent-id="0">Name 1</div>
    <div class="sortItem" parent-id="1">Name 2</div>
    <div class="sortItem" parent-id="1">Name 3</div>
    <div class="sortItem" parent-id="0">Name 4</div>
    <div class="sortItem" parent-id="0">Name 5</div>
</div>
[...and so on...]
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(".sortable:has(.sortItemHead)").sortable({
   items:".sortItemHead:not(.disbaled)",
   cancel:".disabled",
   start:function(event,ui){
      var parentID = ui.item.attr("parent-id");

      jQuery(".sortItemHead[parent-id!='"+parentID+"']").addClass("disbaled");
      jQuery(".sortItemHead[parent-id='"+parentID+"']").removeClass("disbaled");
   },
   stop:function(){
      jQuery(".sortItemHead").removeClass("disbaled");
   }
});
```

...this way, the disabled is set when starting the sorting...sadly, the sortable items are not updated this way...a dirty workaround would be to apply mutiple sortables with

```
items:".sortItemHead[parent-id='"+parentID+"']"
```

...however, that would be pretty ugly code....there has to be a other way...

The second part of the problem is that i want the items to stay syncronous. only the head may be moved...the other items shall behave like the dragged head item...so for all sortable items, the handle would be the respective head element

**[UPDATE]**

problem part 1 was solved through adding

```
jQuery(".sortable:has(.sortItemHead)").sortable( "refresh" );
```

...it's not perfect tough, perfect would be to have the items with the same parent-id move in unision with their parent...

**[UPDATE]**
fiddle for fiddlin': http://jsfiddle.net/k34CZ/1/
...note that it would be nice to have the elements with parent-id 1 move together with the respective element....but that's optional for the moment...also note that you are'nt able to move the "1" element back to the top, if you move i away...

Comment: For 2nd part, did you tried using handle option for sortable? You can specify head item as the handle for sortable

Comment: yes, i tought of it, i'm working on a possible soultion using the handle option...

Comment: nope, that won't work, since you can only specify one handle per sortable (e.g. a class selector), there is no way to get different handle selectors per item...

Comment: Will it be possible for you to put your code in a fiddle?